# Deploy qml plugin on android within cmake

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake, qml

I am trying to deploy my application for android. The application runs my main.qml within QQuickView. My main.qml imports a custom module, which I also wrote. My project is based on CMake, thus I am trying to deploy android apk cmake. However, when I am packing the apk with `androiddeployqt`. I have this warning:

> Reading dependencies from Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths:

and plugin files are not deployed to the apk. Is there any solution to manually deploy qmlplugin, so that I can deploy my external qml plugin within CMake (not qmake!)?

Is there any way to feed androiddeployqt path to my plugins, so that it will detect and automatically deploy all required plugin files (not only shared library, but also dozens of internal .qml component files)?

Comment: In a project at work, we did some custom commands to have a plugin on dev-machine (for qt creator) but loaded as static library on android. Maybe you can work around it like this? Anyway, you can add extra libs using https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake (via `DEPENDS`)

Comment: I have already tried specifying my plugin target in DEPENDS using github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake, but internally it points only to a .so file,  and this .so file is actually deployed to the apk. But other files, like qmldir and component qml files are not copied to an android apk.
Another problem is that the copied library file is resided in `<package-name>/lib` directory, which is also a problem, while qml engine needs all plugin files to be resided in `${QML_IMPORT_PATHS}/<plugin-name>/*` folder.

Comment: yeah, we did `engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");` and organized stuff accordingly. Maybe you need to load the resources via `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` (use name of the qrc file)?

Comment: Have you compiled all .qml and qmldir files into a qrc, and than linked it to the plugin target file (like add_library(<target> <sources> <qml-and-qmldir-stuff>.qrc))? Or you have somehow copied files to apk. 

Sorry for these questions. I am new to android and not familiar with tools yet..

Comment: It's quite a good question, I'd say ;-) yes we have them compiled as resources. Don't know if androidqtdeploy allows you to bundle files in the "Android way"

Comment: I temporarily worked around this problem by copying my custom qml plugins to standard qt path, where qml plugins have resided. For me it was `/path/to/Qt/5.12.2/android_x86/qml/`. This way androiddeployqt detects my plugin and deploys it with all resources to apk image. As far as I understand internally androiddeployqt puts all resources (qmldir, *.qml files) into the library target file, so the appropriate solution would be to compile all resources into the plugin library file as qrc.